# tlmgr does not update binary

Tags: mactex, tlmgr, update, texlive-2019

I have MacTeX 2019 installed and I am trying to update dvisvgm to the latest version. If I `run tlmgr` info it says:

```
installed:   Yes
revision:    52851
sizes:       doc: 149k, bin: 5061k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 2.8.1
cat-date:    2019-11-15 16:24:37 +0100
cat-license: gpl3+
cat-topics:  dvi-proc
cat-contact-home: https://dvisvgm.de
cat-contact-announce: https://dvisvgm.de/News
cat-contact-repository: https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm
cat-contact-bugs: https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/issues
collection:  collection-binextra`
```

However running `dvisvgm --version` gives me `dvisvgm 2.6.3`. I have tried to update both `dvisvgm` directly and also `collection-binextra` but it does not help. What is it that I am not getting?

Comment: texlive normally doesn't update binaries, so it is quite possible that there is on ctan a newer version than in texlive. I have 2.6.3 too (I could for windows probably get a newer version through w32tex.org)

Comment: OK! Then I will just have to wait for the next release I guess.